# Counting number of even lines from file

Tags: c++, string, file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    ifstream plik;

    plik.open("napisy.txt");
    int nr_line=0;
    string line;
    int ile_parzystych=0;


    cout << "Podpunkt a)=:"<< endl;

    if(plik.good()==false){
        cout << "wrong read of file!"<<endl;
    }

    while(getline(plik,line))
    {
        if( line.length() / 2 == 0) 
        {   

        ile_parzystych++; 
            if(nr_line==1)
            {cout << "to jest pierrwsza linia - jest ona nieparzysta a więc licznik = " << ile_parzystych << endl;}
            if(nr_line==2)
            {cout << "to jest druga linia - jest ona parzysta a więc licznik = " << ile_parzystych << endl;}
        }
    }
    plik.close();
    cout << endl <<  ile_parzystych << " <- Tyle jest linii parzystych";

    }
```

Problem is that I have only this output:

> cout << "Podpunkt a)=:"<< endl;

so it's shows `Podpunkt a)=:`, and

> cout << endl <<  ile_parzystych << " <- Tyle jest linii parzystych"; 0 <- Tyl jest linii parzystych

I don't know why it's not counting.

Comment: n / 2 == 0 does not mean that n is even - use n % 2 == 0

Comment: `line.length() / 2` will only be zero if the length of the line is one or zero.

Comment: Thank you guys, I forgot how to math. ;]

Answer (score 1):

`nr_line` remains at 0 for the whole program, so your loop will never enter the two `if` conditions

```
if (nr_line == 1)
```

and

```
if (nr_line == 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would need to increase nr_line each line?
This way nr_line will never be anything else than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable of `nr_line` always `0`, you don't do any operation on it.
so `if(nr_line==1)` and `if(nr_line==2)` never matched.